# How to separate a string without removing the spaces

Tags: android, arrays, string, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[FireStore Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXgdX.png)

I already retrieve the vaccine name and the number of count but the problem is the SPACE is also replace or being removed.

[Retrived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhxTS.jpg)

I WANT TO OUTPUT THE ITEM LIKE THIS

[WITH SPACE SAME VALUE IN THE FIRE STORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHcPY.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: Yes I've already get it

Answer (score -1):

I ALREADY GET IT USING THIS CODE BELOW IT I HOPE YOU GET THE POINT OF THE CODE BELOW CLICK THE LINKED TEXT TO SEE IT

[IMAGE FOR THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cxhM.png)

Basically I used the Character.isDigit, isAlphabetic, isWhiteSpace
then save it to stringbuffer. then save it to my textview

I assigned my buffer variable for text to get also the whitespace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).